# How to clone Silverlight visual tree structure

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, clone

I have the same problem as the question stated in ["Printing in Silverlight 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745224/printing-in-silverlight-4)".

To get around the problem, I have tried to scale transform root of my visual tree before printing.

```
    void document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        var renderScale = 1.0D;
        if (LayoutRoot.ActualWidth > e.PrintableArea.Width)
            renderScale = e.PrintableArea.Width/LayoutRoot.ActualWidth;

        var scaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();
        scaleTransform.ScaleX *= renderScale;
        scaleTransform.ScaleY *= renderScale;

        e.PageVisual = LayoutRoot;
        e.PageVisual.RenderTransform = scaleTransform;
    }
```

Now above code correctly prints out with silverlight visuals fit on a piece of paper.

The problem now is that `LayoutRoot` itself is now scaled down on the screen.

The question is, is there a way for me to create a clone of `LayoutRoot` before applying scale transform?

My walk-around is to applying the scale tranformation again after printing but I'd like to know if there is a way to clone visual tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My goodness, thanks for the question. I had the same problem but tried to fiddle about with setting the dimensions of a container (that is already in the visual tree) to the printable area, which does *not* work, as another layout pass seems to be required. `ScaleTransform` *does* work here however instantly.

I'm fine with the "work around" by just doing a `myContainer.ClearValue(FrameworkElement.RenderTransformProperty)` in the `EndPrint` event. Trying to clone the visual tree will yield a plethora of other issues (I have lazy loading content etc).

Comment: Thanks, herzmeister.  I haven't thought about actually "clearing" container value.  It seems like a better approach than my saving old render scale value and then re-transforming it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [link](http://yinyangme.com/blog/post/Generic-class-for-deep-clone-of-Silverlight-and-C-objects.aspx) for details on silverlight object clone.

also just another idea would using xamlreader/writer to read the xaml string and creating an in-memory copy of the visual tree work.

for ex

**If your xaml has button called originalbutton, using the code below you will have a copy of the button in readerLoadButton**

```
// Save the Button to a string.
string savedButton = XamlWriter.Save(originalButton);

// Load the button
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(savedButton);
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
Button readerLoadButton = (Button)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

Comment: XamlWriter/Reader are available only in WPF.